# unable using C++23 with CMake+clangd+MSVC+VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, c++23, clangd

I'm using **CMake** generator and **MSVC** compiler with VSCode editor while programming C++, but something troubled me when I try to switch language support extension to `clangd`.
It works correctly set `CXX_STANDARD` to C++20, but when I tried upgrading to C++23, CMake generates "`-std:c++latest`" instead of "`-std:c++23`" to `compile_commands.json`. In my source files, both macro `__cplusplus` and `_MSVC_LANG` equals to `201402L`, not `2023xxL`. (But I can normally compile C++23 features)

Do CMake and clangd support c++23? I found that there was `-std:c++23` support for Clang in its official documentation, But it either not works when I manually replaced "-std:c++latest" to "-std:C++23".

My clangd and CMake are in newest versions.

---

My configurations:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JYf6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDAQQ.png)

---

How It works in C++20 standard:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuLar.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1h4F.png)

---

How it doesn't work in C++23 standard: (clangd says it is c++14!)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNC4f.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okvu1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvihM.png)

I tried to manually replaced "-std:c++latest" to "-std:C++23", then upgraded CMake and clangd version newest. But problen still exsits.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** which represent textual information. Instead, paste to the question post the code as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: What clangd version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Clangd bug](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1850) (or [this one](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/527)).

The workaround is to add following to `.clangd` (config file in your project dir):

```yaml
CompileFlags:
  Add: ['-std:c++latest']
```